# Technical reasons to use <ul> tag in navigation bars. Is there any?

Tags: css, html, navigation, html-lists, nav

Are there any technical reasons (CSS / jQuery related) why to use `<ul>` tag for navigation bars, instead of just using `a` tags?

```
<nav>
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="/">Home page</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About page</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

vs

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home page</a>
    <a href="/about">About page</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Even though I've provided an answer, I'm not sure this is *entirely* on-topic - be prepared for people suggesting it be closed.

Comment: Definitely not on topic - this should be on doctype or on stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- It's, arguably, 'more semantic': those links probably *are* a list
- Without the `nav` element, (i.e. in HTML5), the `ul` often provides a useful container for styling

Comment: It's also more likely to appear as a vertical list of items if your stylesheet doesn't get loaded for whatever reason.

Comment: right. But with html5 the `nav` element already mean a list of links that form a navigation.

Comment: @Mendy - actually, it does not mean a list of links. It means "a section with navigation links". If you look at the examples that the W3C provides for the [nav element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element) they all use a <ul> within.

Answer (score -2):

Unlike XML, you cannot make-up tags in HTML. Sure,  will probably work but it's invalid mark-up.

Lists usually provide a nice way to mark things up that make sense. Structure, it usually makes sense (you typically have a list of items in your navigation, no?). Definition lists can lend themselves to some forms of navigation but lists usually make the most sense.

Comment: Which tag is made up? Did you mean [nav](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element)?

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that he's using nav imply that he's using HTML5?